'Naive cotangent complex' is the one truncated of the cotangent complex
In the stacks project, there is a 'naive version' of cotangent complex $NL_{S/R}$ for a ring morphism $R\rightarrow S$, given by the chan complex $(I/I^{2}\rightarrow \Omega_{R[S]/R}\otimes_{R[S]}S)$ where $I$ is the kernel of the morphism $R[S]\rightarrow S$ (here $R[S]$ is the $0$ th term of the simplicial resolution of $S$ as algebra). In stacks, there is a claim that this naive chain complex is the 1-truncation of cotangent complex $L_{S/R}$.
$\textbf{It really confuses me how this claim is proved}$. Let's first start with the simplicial module induced by the simplicial resolution of $S$ as $R$ algebra: $\cdots\Omega_{R[R[R[S]]]/R}\otimes_{R[R[R[S]]]}S\stackrel{d^{2}_{0},d^{2}_{1},d^{2}_{2}}{\longrightarrow}\Omega_{R[R[S]]/R}\otimes_{R[R[S]]}S\stackrel{d^{1}_{0},d^{1}_{1}}{\longrightarrow}\Omega_{R[S]/R}\otimes_{R[S]}S$, and this simplicial resolution corresponds to a chain complex by normalized chain functor, which looks like $\cap_{i=1,2}ker(d^{1}_{i})\stackrel{d_{0}^{2}}{\longrightarrow}\cap_{i=1}ker(d^{1}_{1})\stackrel{d_{1}^{0}}{\longrightarrow}\Omega_{R[S]/R}\otimes_{R[S]}S$. For the 1 truncation of this chain complex, by definition of truncation of chain complex, should be the $coker(d_{0}^{2})\rightarrow \Omega_{R[S]/R}\otimes_{R[S]}S$.
$\textbf{Question:}$ How do we prove this $coker(d_{0}^{2})$ is isomorphic to $I/I^{2}$, or if this should be quasi-isomoprhism, $ker(coker(d_{0}^{2})\rightarrow \Omega_{R[S]/R}\otimes_{R[S]}S)$ is isomorphic to $ker(I/I^{2}\rightarrow \Omega_{R[S]/R}\otimes_{R[S]}S)$? Is there any way better than direct calculation?
